# Internal workings of gridview control? how to create custom (databound) controls

Tags: asp.net, gridview, custom-controls, lifecycle

I want to know complete life cycle of gridview control (control's life cycle) in context with the page life cycle.

What all events are fired. How the data gets bind (i mean which events are internally fired and when are they fired).

Actually i am looking to create the repository of complex custom controls (required in day to day life). Once i am aware of how the server control works(eg:- gridview control) i would be comfortable in creating custom controls.

Also please suggest some ideas as to what kinda custom controls are needed (eg:- custom pager control)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create custom data bound controls, take a look at the tutorials on MSDN:
[Developing Custom Data-Bound Web Server Controls for ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366539.aspx)

[Walkthrough: Creating a Custom Data-Bound ASP.NET Web Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366540.aspx)

But I would be very surprised if you really needed to create multiple complex data bound controls. The standard ASP.NET controls, such as the GridView, are very flexible and should meet 90% of your requirements.